# Using the Windows batch file "for /r" command to enumerate directories

Tags: batch-file

I want to find all directories named `.ttranscoded` in the current tree. But issuing `for /r %d in (.transcoded*) do echo %d` produces no output. What am I missing?

Comment: please use `(.ttranscoded*)` instead of `(.transcoded*)`

Answer (score 2):

As you are looking for a directory you'd need to use the /D option too:

```dos
for /d /r %a in (.ttranscoded*) do @echo(%a
```

you'll need to bear in mind that this will only find matches which begin with .ttranscoded so you may prefer something like this:

```dos
for /d /r %a in (.t?ranscoded) do @echo(%a
```

…the idea being that you're replacing a letter unlikely to be anything else with a single character wildcard.

Comment: Thanks @Compo. Even your format finds no `.t?ranscoded` folders even though `d .t?ranscoded /s` does. What else could I try?

Comment: @DeanHannotte - Compo's code works perfectly for me on the command line. You must double the percents if you put the code within a batch script.

Answer (score 1):

Windows has a significant shortcoming when it comes to listing folder names.

You cannot directly search a folder hierarchy for a specific folder name with either `FOR /R /D` or `DIR /S /B /AD`. The best you can do is add at least one wild card to the mask ([As Compo has done](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40357424/1012053)), but then you run a risk of returning extra folders that you don't want.

You can easily eliminate unwanted matches by adding an additional command.

Using FOR /R /D plus IF

```
for /r /d %%F in (.t?ranscoded) do if /i "%%~nxF" equ ".ttranscoded" (
  echo %%F
)
```

Using DIR /S /B /AD plus FINDSTR

```
dir /s /b /ad .t?ranscoded | findstr /lxic:".ttranscoded"
```

Another option is to use my [JREN.BAT utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6081). It is a hybrid batch/JScript script that is designed to rename files/folders using regular expressions. But it can also be used to do more sophisticated directory listings than can be done with native commands. JREN.BAT runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward - no 3rd party exe file is required.

```
jren "^.*" "path()" /list /j /s /d /fm .ttranscoded
```